# adding a field somehow effects a views results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Have a very odd situation.  For various reasons we have a bunch of tables where this was done:

TableA was renamed to TableASource and a view was created called TableA
TableB was renamed to TableBSource and a view was created called TableB

This all works fine and has done for a fair while.  Yesterday I added a new field to TableASource, TableBSource (and the others).  This was a field called 'createDate' a smallDateTime, no nulls with a default value of getDate().  You would think this should have zero impact on anything.  Today first thing users are saying they can see these dates inplace of the intended data.  E.G Lest says we had a page extracting 10 fields out of the view called TableA, instead of showing these 10 fields its now showing 9 correctly and randomly showing the value in the new createDate field that was added to TableASource (If it matters it placing it in the second field on the page)

I quickly dropped all these new createDate fields and the issue went away.  How can this possibly happen?  How can adding a field to TableASource effect the results of the TableA view?

Using SQLServer2008 r2

in response the the extra questions below.  Here is the view called 'bayTrainCourses' which has been described above as TableA :

```
SELECT  btc.course_id, btc.course_name, btc.course_status, btc.course_expiry, btc.course_startdate, btc.course_enddate, btc.course_type, btc.site_id, btc.channelid, btc.exam_type, btc.enroll_type, btc.last_updated, btc.compid, btc.TOC, btc.rdone, btc.autoqualify, btc.courseIntroId, btc.coursePurposeId, btc.courseBackgroundId,btc.courseObjectivesId, intro.    [content] AS course_intro, purpose.[content] AS course_purpose, background.[content] AS course_background, 
objectives.[content] AS course_objectives
FROM dbo.bayTrainCoursesSource AS btc 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RTE AS intro ON btc.courseIntroId = intro.pk 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RTE AS purpose ON btc.coursePurposeId = purpose.pk 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RTE AS background ON btc.courseBackgroundId = background.pk 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.RTE AS objectives ON btc.courseObjectivesId = objectives.pk
```

The select is:

```
select * from baytraincourses....
```

EDITING - due to some trial an error.  It turns out that the trial was actually  the advice from JohnS below.  Recreate the view....   I renamed the view to baytraincourses_broken.  Then right click > script view as > create to > then I changed 'baytraincourses_broken' to 'baytraincourses' to recreate another version with the original name.  Now the page works.

I am not a big fan of views. Its very rare I create them to be honest, I am working with code that I did not originally write.  Do I really have to re-create views every time I add a new column?  Surely not, how can I deal with this?

Comment: When you load the 10 columns into your page from the database, what query are you running? Something like: ^Select * from TableA^? And at what position did you add the column? Inbetween others or at the 'end'?

Comment: Can you show us the script for the views?

Comment: Yes select * from TableA.  The column was added to the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the new field to TableASource you need to recreate the view. (i.e. DROP VIEW TableA ... then CREATE VIEW TableA ...).

Comment: Absolutely not, this won't help.

Comment: well now I am very confused.  This did work.  REALLY, do I have to re-create views after adding a column to a table?? Surely not!   I have updated my original post with the difference in the views

Comment: Despite DavidG's comment, I have encountered the same symptoms myself. Recreating the view has always fixed it. @DavidG you might consider reversing your downvote!

Comment: @Mat41, If this answer worked you might consider accepting this answer. I routinely generate a DROP/CREATE script for any views that are dependant on the restructured table.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557515/how-to-rebuild-view-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Yes it is correct for me to accept your answer because recreating the view does fix my issue.  Please note - there is a quicker way that DROP and CREATE.  sp_refreshview 'yourViewName' gives the same outcome.  Although this is a solution I am far from happy with it.  we really have to do this every time we add a field to a table.  Perhaps this deserves another post

Comment: @Mat41. Yes sp_refreshview is a better solution. However, rebuilding your view either way is not such an onerous task. How often do you add or remove columns?

Comment: Not if you have 70+ views which you didn't originally write therefore have no idea which ones need refreshing every time you add a data base column.  Its's nightmare IMO.  I should be able to add what ever column what ever table anytime without any impact frankly.  A business unit can raise a request for any kind of change that may required any number of fields anytime

Comment: Yeah I understand your problem. Perhaps you need a script that that walks through all the views and calls sp_refreshview for each.

Comment: My downvote still stands as dropping any object and recreating it does more than just recreating the object. At the very least you lose any explicit permissions assigned to the view.