# SQL Server why must I refresh views after table changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, view

This question came out of a previous post/solution of mine:

[adding a field somehow effects a views results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28552763/adding-a-field-somehow-effects-a-views-results)

IMO it deserves its own post. Using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Why do I have to refresh views after adding a column to a table which is referenced in the view? Although not directly necessary to answer this post/question, the scenario/behavior for my specific scenario is explained the the post linked above.

I am not a big fan of views. Its very rare I create them to be honest, I am working with code that I did not originally write. Let's say you have 70+ views which you didn't originally write therefore have no idea which ones need refreshing every time you add a data base column. I should be able to add what ever column what ever table anytime without any impact frankly. A business unit can raise a request for any kind of change that may required any number of fields added anytime.

Surely there is another approach to this?

Comment: A view is not just a query, dynamically reorganizing itself every time it's called. It's instantiated with a schema, columns and so forth. There are many cases (such as the one in the link you referenced) where adding additional columns to a result set could behave unexpectedly. While this sort of goes the opposite direction of the more lax implementation you want, views can also be declared with the SCHEMABINDING option, which prohibits schema changes to underlying objects. However, as was noted in several places, if you want a schema to pick up a new column, you have to use sp_refreshview

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Although I don't like it,  it make sense.  I do realize there is resource efficiency advantage to views.  This said, I'm fairly sure I like them even less now.  The end user experience I have seen today as a result of adding a column to a table was uvery erratic

Comment: Views are not always bad. They are great for simplifying complex queries, standardizing business rules in queries that may be shared across apps or stored procs, enable you to write a rename fields or simplify queries against third party databases (especially legacy ones with archaic names, like AE1401 as a table name with fields FN144, etc), and when apps share a table, if underlying table field must change, the view name can remain the same not forcing you to change multiple apps.

Comment: Views can also provide great performance improvements in certain scenarios where you can index and materialize the data returned the view, or consolidate data that may be horizontally sharded across multiple tables due to performance concerns and table sizes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the dynamic management views to identify which views were impacted by your table change, then loop through the results of the impacted views to use dynamic sql to call `sp_refreshview` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821(v=sql.105).aspx)

Here's a quick script you could adapt to a stored proc if you want:

```
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(500) = 'dbo.Accounts'

DECLARE @ViewsToUpdate TABLE (ViewName VARCHAR(500))
    INSERT @ViewsToUpdate
        SELECT
            Views.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + Views.TABLE_NAME
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES [Views]
            INNER JOIN sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(@TableName, 'OBJECT') DependingViews
                ON DependingViews.referencing_schema_name = Views.TABLE_SCHEMA
                    AND DependingViews.referencing_entity_name = Views.TABLE_NAME
        WHERE [Views].TABLE_TYPE = 'View'

WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @ViewsToUpdate) BEGIN
    DECLARE @ViewName VARCHAR(500) = (SELECT TOP 1 ViewName FROM @ViewsToUpdate)
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(1000) = 'EXEC sp_refreshview ''' + @ViewName + ''''
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @Sql
    DELETE @ViewsToUpdate WHERE ViewName = @ViewName
END
```

Comment: Added code sample to auto-refresh views related to a selected table

Comment: Thank you for your time.  I will need to wait for an approval to reproduce the issue and then run/test this but it certainly looks like a good solution to sweep all the necessary views!

Comment: Another feature I just though of, which might be hepful, if it's as simple as referencing a table wholesale, is the SYNONYM feature. This, as the name suggests just creates an alias for a table which directly sends your query along to the object it synonymizes (is that a word?). Then, if you add a column to that object, it's automatically included since it basically IS the underlying object.

Comment: never used SYNONYM before.  Just had a read, sure looks like good way to abstract a server and/or database location.  I dont however understand how this can effectively 'refresh' my view after adding a new field